# Issue with MySQL Select

Tags: php, mysql

I'm building a website to learn coding. I have a claim.php which is a claim your business page (its just a place that you can search for a business and then click a link to addclaimedbiz.php) and a addclaimedbiz.php page which adds the claimed business to the database.

First of all, heres my sql code for the user where the business id will be added to the row **biz**:

```
`id` int(15) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`firstname` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`lastname` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`email` varchar(75) NOT NULL,
`password` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`biz` int(1) NOT NULL,
`verifiedbiz` int(1) NOT NULL,
```

and heres my sql code for the businesses:

```
`id` int(15) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`phone` varchar(14) NOT NULL,
`claimed` int(1) NOT NULL,
```

Now heres the code for claim.php that sends the company id to addclaimedbiz.php. ( I only posted a little but can post more if you need it!)

```
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {
            $id=$row['id'];
            $company_name=$row['name'];
            $company_phone=$row['phone'];
            $company_address=$row['address'];
            $address2=$row['address2'];
            $company_city=$row['city'];
            $company_zip=$row['zipcode'];
            $cat1=$row['cat1'];
            $cat2=$row['cat2'];
            $cat3=$row['cat3'];
            $subcat1=$row['subcat1'];
            $subcat2=$row['subcat2'];
            $subcat3=$row['subcat3'];
            $claimed=$row['claimed'];
            //Start While Loop
            echo"
            <div class='listing'>
                                    <li>
                                        <span class='bphone'>$company_phone</span>
                                        <span class='bname'>$company_name</span>
                                        <br/>
                                        <div class='blocation'>$company_address, $company_city, CO $company_zip ";if($address2 != ""){echo"(".$address2.")";}echo"</div>
                                        <br/>
                                        ";if($claimed != 1){echo "<a href='addclaimedbiz.php?id=".$id."'><button>Claim Business</button></a>";}else{echo "Already Claimed";}echo"
                                    </li>

                                <!--/Listing-->

                </div>";

            }
```

And then heres my code for addclaimedbiz.php:

```
 <?
 $biz_id = $_REQUEST['id'];

 //This next select from db is to take the id of the company and get the name for the corresponding id

 include("./config.php");
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM company WHERE id = '$biz_id'") or die(mysql_error());
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
 {
    $business_name = $row['name'];
 }

 ?>
```

and then to echo out $business_name i use (this is on addclaimedbiz.php as well just down the page a bit)

```
<?php if($biz == "0"){

            echo "You are claiming:"$business_name " as your business";

            }
            else{"You are already have a claimed business"}
            ?>
```

What should be happening is it should echo out You are claiming: $business_name as your business but right now its leaving out $business_name. Why is this?

Major thanks to all help!

Oh and I left out some of the rows in my databases that were unnecessary to the problem I thought, but if you need them I can definitely post!

---

EDIT

---

my new code looks like this:

```
<?
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$auth = $_COOKIE["auth"];
if ($auth != "1"){
header("Location: ./signin.php");
}
$firstname = $_COOKIE['firstname'];
$id = $_COOKIE['id'];
$fname = ucwords($_COOKIE['firstname']);
$lname = ucwords($_COOKIE['lastname']);
$email = $_COOKIE['email'];
$city = ucwords($_COOKIE['city']);
$biz = ucwords($_COOKIE['biz']);

$biz_id = $_REQUEST['id'];

include("./config.php");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM company WHERE id = '$biz_id'") or die(mysql_error());
if(mysql_num_rows($result)){
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $business_name = $row['name'];
    }
}
echo count($result);
?>
```

Comment: `echo "You are claiming:" .$business_name. " as your business";`

Comment: What you're doing is leaving yourself open for SQL injection attacks. If someone enters a biz_id of `';DROP TABLE company;--,` then you'll be deleting your entire company table. Please see http://bobby-tables.com/php.html for details on how to use bind parameters.

Comment: you forgot to `echo` in your else block at the end

Comment: @AndyLester...Woah, thanks, that could have been bad especially since i'm just about to put this site live

Comment: why no errors being thrown? have you set error_reporting to 0 ?

Comment: @Blaine Thanks, typed that part up just as I was putting it up here!

Comment: @amitchhajer, thanks for saying that. I turned them on and the error is: Notice: Undefined variable: business_name in addclaimedbiz.php on line 43

Comment: and line 43 is?
 echo "You are claiming:"$business_name " as your business"; ?
and you have changed it to  echo "You are claiming:".$business_name ". as your business";
also try using mysql_fetch_assoc in place of fetch_array as you arr using named elements

Comment: @amitchhajer, Thanks, line 43 is `echo "You are claiming:" . $business_name . " as your business";`, and I just changed mysql_fetch_array to mysql_fetch_assoc but its still not echoing out?

Comment: can you echo $row['name'] and check if something is coming?

Comment: @amitchhajer, $row['name'] doesn't echo out anything either?

Comment: are you sure, there is 'name' column in table company? because you said $result is not null, try echo count($result) once.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14879/discussion-between-amitchhajer-and-jake)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not using proper variable interpolation in your string, put `$business_name` inside the qutoes:

```
echo "You are claiming:$business_name as your business";
```

Ah, also looks like you want `mysql_fetch_assoc`, not `mysql_fetch_array`:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $business_name = $row['name'];
}
```

[Docs here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php).

Hmmm...I have a hunch, try wrapping your `while` block with:

```
if(mysql_num_rows($result)){
   ...   
}
```

I'll let someone else do the lecturing on the mysql_* functions.  :)

Cheers

Comment: Thanks @madbreaks, I tried that, but still nothing. Could it be that I'm still using mysql instead of mysqli? When I went to the docs it came up with an error saying:Use of this extension is discouraged.?

Comment: No, mysql will *work*.  You say "still nothing".  What exactly are you seeing?

Comment: I turned on error reporting and got the following error: _Notice: Undefined variable: business_name in addclaimedbiz.php on line 41_ So far the output is still the same, its still "You are claiming: as your business" without the $business_name?

Comment: line 41 is where I echo out the $business_name

Comment: Thanks, but it still says $business_name is undefined...Could it be something wrong with my config file?

Comment: Please update your code to reflect the changes you're making. Are you sure there's a value in the database for that field?  Can you run the query from the MySQL cli and get a valid result?

Comment: Sorry @Madbreaks...I'll update my code in the question in just a second, and I just checked all the rows and they valid results, and values in the database for the id.?

Comment: thanks I figured it out! For some reason $_REQUEST['id']; was giving me an incorrect value back so I had to switch it to $_GET['id']

Comment: The answer you accepted as correct is invalid syntax. You sure you chose the right one?  ;)

Answer (score 1):

You need to concatenate the strings with a period like so:

```
        echo "You are claiming:" . $business_name . " as your business";
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Unfortunately, it's still not echoing $business_name? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to put a couple `.` in your `echo` statement.

Like this:

`echo "You are claiming: " . $business_name . " as your business";`

Comment: If you're using string concatenation, better to use single quotes around your string parts.  Otherwise just put the variable in the string and let PHP handle the interpolation.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Unfortunately, it's still not echoing $business_name? Any ideas?

Comment: is the mysql query returning anything ? try var_dump($result)

Comment: Ok, it came back with "resource(4) of type (mysql result)"

Comment: Ok, the new error is Notice: Undefined variable: business_name in addclaimedbiz.php on line 43

Answer (score 0):

You need to use . to concatenate strings in php

```
 echo "You are claiming:".$business_name ". as your business"
```

Comment: I turned on error reporting and the error is now: Notice: Undefined variable: business_name in addclaimedbiz.php on line 43

Comment: @Jake and line 43 is? echo "You are claiming:"$business_name " as your business"; ? and you have changed it to echo "You are claiming:".$business_name " . as your business"; right? also try using mysql_fetch_assoc in place of fetch_array as you using named elements

Comment: @Jake putting 
`while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
 {
    $business_name = $row['name'];
 }`
is making no sense, loop is assigning some $row['name'] from table again and again to $business_name.

Comment: Ok what should it be instead?

Comment: *you* need to use `.` to concatenate strings.  lulz